# Installing Angular with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: angular, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'll preface this by saying I have little to zero experience with Angular.

I have an existing Web API project using Angular on the front-end. I was given two links to check out and I have been trying to follow the steps listed [here](https://angular.io/guide/visual-studio-2015) and [here](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart) to install Angular but dozens of errors persist.

Here are the some of the errors I continue to see:

> Build:Cannot find module 'XXX'
>
> Cannot find module XXX
>
> Build:Parameter 'XXX' implicitly as an 'any' type
>
> Parameter 'XXX' implicitly as an 'any' type

My node version is v8.9.4 and my npm version is v5.6.0. One thing I have not tried yet is uninstalling everything I've installed so far and starting over.

If this is the complete opposite of installing Angular or if you have any other advice on how to correctly install Angular, just give it to me straight.

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you pasted an example of an actual error message from the shell, including the stack trace, so it's easier to pinpoint where the error is occurring.

Comment: Also, please specify the versions of Angular and Angular CLI that you're using. If it's Angular 2 or above, please remove the "angularjs" tag, as "angularjs" refers to the first version of Angular, which is rather different and not compatible with Angular 2+

Comment: @dukeluke I have posted the a screenshot but I don't think it'll be of too much help. About the versions, I will look into that and post another update for it. Thanks

Comment: What can I do to improve the question? What's with the downvotes?

Comment: You need to be more specific about your problem. "Installing Angular" is extremely vague, since Angular is just a framework you use to create an app. What command is causing your errors? Is it when you try to install the Angular CLI by running `npm install -g @angular/cli`? Or are these errors being thrown by Visual Studio's interpreter?

As it is, your post gives almost no context around these "Installing Angular" errors.

Comment: For Angular and Angular CLI versions, run `ng --version` in the shell

Comment: @dukeluke Ah, I understand now (on both parts). I'll get that on the next update

Comment: @dukeluke I think it might have something to do with a proxy

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Visual Studio, but those errors seem like they have more to do with the Angular CLI than your IDE.

Assuming you're using Angular 2+ (and not angularjs), there is one important step required to set up an existing Angular app that won't be in the quickstart guide:

After installing the Angular CLI, `cd` into the project directory containing the `package.json` file and run `npm install`. After installing all dependencies, you should be able to run `ng serve` without issue.

(Note: if you're following the [official quickstart guide](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart), you should ignore step two, as that's only for creating a new project.)